# How to implement PaintCode project into SKScene

Tags: ios, swift, paintcode

In my app I'd like to implement a circle made with PaintCode (`Stylekit`) in `SKScene`.

This is my code:

```
import SpriteKit
import GameplayKit

class GameScene: SKScene {

  override init(size: CGSize) {
    super.init(size: size)     
    StyleKit.drawCanvas1()
  }

  required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
  }

  override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
  }
}
```

How can I resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you might build the `SKSpriteNode` in this way:

```
func makeCircle(width:CGFloat = 200, height:CGFloat = 200) -> SKSpriteNode? {
  let size = CGSize(width: width, height: height)
  UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, false, 0)
  StyleKit.drawCircle(frame: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: size), resizing: .AspectFit)
  let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
  UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
  if let safeImage = image {
    return SKSpriteNode(texture: SKTexture(image: safeImage))
  } else {
    return nil
  }
}
```